# Are there any standard HTML meta properties?

Tags: html

Hello is there any standard HTML I have to put before and between `<head></head>`.
If yes what are they?

Comment: there are many like [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a [defined metadata name](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.name.html#defined-metadata-name):

- `application-name`
- `author`
- `description`
- `generator`
- `keywords`

Or a [registered metadata name](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions).